# contemporaneously VERSUS simultaneously

Tags: meaning

IS there a difference between **contemporaneously** and **simultaneously**?

Are they 100% identical in meaning

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the difference in timescale.

Simultaneously is almost 'at the very same moment'.

> The sun came out and simultaneously a rainbow formed.

Contemporaneously is over a longer period, often 'someone's lifetime'.

> Pythagoras was contemporaneous with Buddha.

Comment: Contemporaneously means overlapping partly?

Comment: I don't think the overlap/overspill is important to the definition, it's that there is conjunction of the two items/people in a rough space of time. Perhaps you wouldn't be so inclined to use contemporaneous if the first person died when the second was only 1 year old, but I don't think there's really any great precision in it.

Comment: So, the difference is that contemporaneous covers  relatively long periods of time?